# Way to visualize the live working of Hyperledger Fabric V1.0

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain.info-api

Is there any tools available  to ***show a graphical representation*** of the things happening in **Hyperledger Fabric V1.0** block chain network? Like displaying the peers joined with the networks, indicating if there occurred a successful transaction etc. Since we doing presentation about this topic, if I can show something visually, it will give more clarity to every listeners who are not much aware about the technical things behind the scene. Currently I have only the locally setup network and some sdk client which are interacting with the network. But it will not be enough for presenting it effectively. Can anyone suggest something to add for giving a clear picture to end users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible alternative of visualizing interaction between Hyperledger Fabric network entities, might be to use [weaveworks](https://github.com/weaveworks/scope). It creates application map based on interaction between docker containers, allows you to monitor and understand relations.

Of course if you need more fine grained control to leverage event hub as suggested by @yacovm is very good option.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to utilize the eventhub channel and subscribe to block events as a start. 
Regarding peers that joined the network - right now that's not possible to list the peers in the network by querying a peer.

Another thing you can do alternatively is periodically query QSCC and CSCC system chaincode for all kinds of data like the chaincodes the peer has installed, the channels it joined to, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I can show the peers and containers by running `docker ps` command that is an option. "suggest to utilize the eventhub channel and subscribe to block events as a start" - sorry, I didn't get this correctly. can you please give some more hints.

Comment: what SDK are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used the java SDK before.
Take a look here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdk/EventHub.java
And also ask in https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-sdk-java if you have questions.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for the inputs given :)